NX 20.2.2 + Angular 19 + Ionic 8 + Jest : Broken tests following latest updates
I have been maintaining Ionic-Angular applications within an NX monorepo (without nxtend/nxext) for a while and it's been going well so far.
However, the last migration to NX 20.2.2 + Angular 19 has broken my Jest tests with those kind of errors:
    import { __awaiter } from "tslib";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

This was typically fixed in jest.config.ts by changing the "transformIgnorePattern" to include some packages from node_modules so that they are included in the ts-jest compilation.
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!.*.mjs$|@ionic/core|@stencil/core|ionicons)'],

But the latest version has broken that and I don't know who the culprit is (NX, jest-preset-angular, my own configuration, something else?).
I've been trying to fix this with no success and I don't know where I should report a bug.
Can anyone help?
I'm including a simple project to reproduce the problem. By going through the commits, you can see the tests initally broken, then fixed, then broken after the migration.
Project:
https://github.com/ddx001/nx-ng-ionic
To run, checkout the project and run:
npm install
npx nx run myapp:test


please include steps to run the tests

Of course. I added the info in the question.

We experience the same.

Experiencing the same issue. Tried several solutions but nothing is working. Only thing what came in my mind to fix it or to postpone the fix is to downgrading unfortunately

After some investigation, I found a really helpful thread with a solution: Jest fix for ionic/stencil
To make it short: downgrade typescript to ~5.5.x. This helped me and now the tests are running again. Looks like the issue is still not solved by Ionic.
But at least, it is a quick fix. And btw. I have the same setupas you.

Yes!!! That works for me too, thank you!!! It looks like TypeScript 5.5 is the recommended (minimal) version for Angular 19 (https://angular.dev/update-guide?v=18.0-19.0&l=1) but it was bumped to 5.6 by the NX migration. I'm going to comment / follow the thread for a more permanent solution but this will do fine as a workaround for the moment.
